# Explicit expression of WZ term for orthogonal groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mp.mathematical-physics

Consider the Wess Zumino term on the the space $W=I\times D$, where D is a two dimensional disk disk and $I$ is an interval, $[0,1]$, say, i.e.,
$$
\int_{I\times  D} \langle(u^{-1} \, du)^3\rangle
$$
where $u: W\rightarrow G$ and $G$ is the $SO(p,q)$ group. I expect that this integral can be expressed as
$$
\int_{\partial(I\times  D)} F
$$
where $F$ is a two-form. Does anybody know where I can find an explicit expression for $F$ in the case of low dimensional group, i.e., small $p$ and $q$ (in fact I'm only interested in the case $p,q\leq 3$.) Thank you.

Comment: I changed $<(u^{-1}du)>$ to $\langle(u^{-1} \, du)\rangle$.